# SSH escape key ("~") only works when connection is stuck?

Tags: ssh, openssh

When I have an unresponsive SSH connection, I can kill it with `<enter>~.`. However, when the connection is responding, the `~` escape doesn't work. It just prints a tilda at the console.

So if I want to modify SSH port forwarding and press `<enter>~C<enter>`, all I get is:

`~C: command not found`

(From `bash`, not from `ssh`.)

What do I need to do so that the SSH escape key works properly?

**EDIT:** I have found a big clue: the remote shell was actually `ash`, not `bash`. When I run `bash` on the remote machine, the SSH escape key works! When I run `ash` inside `bash` inside `ash`, again, it doesn't work!

But this is very strange. The escape key should be caught by the SSH client and not even forwarded to the remote shell. So why should it matter exactly which remote shell is receiving input from SSH?

Comment: `~.` and `~C` work for me in Bash too (when using SSH on a Mac).

Comment: In case it makes a difference, `ssh -V` prints `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`.

Comment: On my up-to-date Mac it's much older, OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011...

Comment: Just in case it might be related to the remote SSH server: I get the same (expected) behaviour when using `ssh localhost`. The remote host I tested with earlier shows OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008. Wow... ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple workaround: run the `cat` command, then enter the escape sequence.

The `cat` command will by default print what is passed in `stdin`, so while it's running there will be no escape characters sent and you can use the ssh escape key as normal. When done just `ctrl-c` out of `cat` back to the shell.

**Example**
If needed, open up a prompt and execute `cat` by typing `cat` and pressing enter.

```
$ 
$ cat
```

Now type ~?

```
~?
Supported escape sequences:
 ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
 ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
 ~C   - open a command line
 ~R   - request rekey
 ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
 ~^Z  - suspend ssh
 ~#   - list forwarded connections
 ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
 ~?   - this message
 ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
```

It works! Now just enter any command. Then to return to prompt press control-C.

```
^C
$
```

Comment: This is so simple that I have no idea what you are suggesting to do.  Can you expand on your answer a bit?

Comment: Kindly Edit your answer and write more details in order to help users understand

Comment: Wow awesome! That works. It should be marked as the answer. I added an example to hopefully make it more comprehensible for others.

Answer (score 14):

I've figured out the secret!

As I posted in the "edit" above, the remote shell was BusyBox `ash`, not `bash`.

From `libbb/lineedit.c:2336-2338`, in the BusyBox sources:

```
/* Print out the command prompt, optionally ask where cursor is */
parse_and_put_prompt(prompt);
ask_terminal();
```

That is used to print out the command prompt in `ash`. But notice, as soon as it prints the prompt, another function called `ask_terminal` is called. What does `ask_terminal` do? It prints out the following characters: `<ESCAPE>[6n`.

You never see those characters in your terminal. Actually, they are an ANSI terminal control escape code. `<ESC>[6n` is a "Query Cursor Position" command -- it tells the terminal emulator to send back another ANSI escape code, which tells the shell where the cursor (text insertion point) is located in the terminal window.

So as soon as you press `Enter`, `ash` prints out `<ESC>[6n`, and `sshd` passes that back to `ssh` and from there to the terminal emulator. Immediately, before you can press `~`, your terminal emulator sends something like `<ESC>[47;13R` to standard input, and `ssh` passes that over the connection to `sshd` and from there to `ash`, telling `ash` where your cursor is.

Now, the SSH client doesn't actually know what those ANSI escape codes mean. To SSH, they are all just characters read from standard input. Rather than seeing `<ENTER>~C`, the SSH client sees `<ENTER><ESC>[47;13R~C`, and since it doesn't see the `~` right after `Enter`, it doesn't think that it is an escape code.

The question is what to do about this. It would be nice if OpenSSH understood those ANSI escapes sent by the terminal and would still accept the `~` escape character after an ANSI terminal control command. I may send the OpenSSH guys a patch and see if they are interested in fixing this...

Comment: Nice find; I'd somehow expect the SSH client to only take the local actual keypresses into account, but your explanation proves me wrong there.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ssh` is a console application and only knows what is sent to its standard input. That is why you can cut-and-paste text into a terminal window where `ssh` is running, and it responds just as if you had typed that text.

Comment: BTW, I sent a patch fixing this to the OpenSSL devs... but it is hanging in limbo, not rejected, but not merged either.

Answer (score 2):

You asked *Surely, the SSH client escape key is not supposed to work like this??*

Yes it should work so:

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>~</kbd> and it will not appear the character `~` on the prompt that escape will be act in the `ssh`.

If you press again <kbd>~</kbd> it will appear on your prompt and it will act on the working shell (the bash in your example), that will try to [expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) and use as it knows.

Note that to work the `~` have to be the first of your *line buffer*, so if you enter any character and after you erase all the line is not anymore *new* and you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

When I press `~?` I obtain

> Supported escape sequences:
>     ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
>     ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
>     ~C  - open a command line
>     ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
>     ~^Z - suspend ssh
>     ~#  - list forwarded connections
>     ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
>     ~?  - this message
>     ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
>   (Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. When I press `Enter`, a newline is sent through SSH to my shell, and the shell responds by displaying a new prompt. Then, when I press `~`, a tilda is sent through SSH to the shell, and the shell displays it after the prompt.

Comment: You are describing how the escape key works *normally*. The whole point of this question is that the escape key is *not* working normally for me.

Comment: This does indeed not answer the question; please delete it so others don't think Alex got an answer.

Comment: @AlexD  Does it works after a manual _Ctrl-J_ or _Ctrl-M_?

Comment: Haha, no of course *"Surely, the SSH client escape key is not supposed to work like this??"* is not the question. The question shows Alex knows what to expect. Again, please delete this.

Comment: @Hastur, `Ctrl-J` and `Ctrl-M` just behave the same as `Enter`. The shell prints a new prompt, and then when I press `~`, it appears at the prompt, as if I am typing a command.

Comment: @Arjan "Haha" is never a proper comment and contradicts in terms the _please_: so, for now, I will ignore both parts. BTW he is an experienced user on another site (more than 17.9k of experience) he should know how to do questions.  For me it is a proper answer, it will not exclude the possibility for others user to answer.   Users that will come on this page should even find it useful...

Comment: (I'd love to remove the "haha" part, but it's too late.)

Comment: I have clarified the question. Even if the question was "should the SSH escape key work like this", this is not a correct answer, because you answer "yes", but then proceed to describe behavior different from what I am seeing (as described in the question).

Comment: Dear @AlexD you are an experienced user.You should put more care when you write a question, even more because you sold you time to solve problems of other people. Here I present to you some of my time. If you dislike the answer and you think it was made without thinking about what you wrote, you can _downvote_ it. Remember that you start with "SSH escape key (“~”) only works...?" and "Surely, the SSH client escape key is not supposed to work like this??". I answered to the 2nd thinking you need confirmations. Now you ask a new one: "...So why should it matter exactly which remote shell is...?"

Comment: @AlexD I think that if you find that the problem was only the `ash` and not `bash` shell on the second system the proper way to proceed should be to post it as an answer,  accept it, then open a new question with the new issue.  Nothing personal of course.